# Should social sciences paper always have policy recommendations?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, social-science

I am an early career researcher and my interests are in education, gender and economic development. I have some research ideas that mainly explore some interesting patterns of behavior at the family level/national level, but I don't think the patterns necessarily have policy implications. Neither can I suggest any actionable policy recommendations based on the observations.

Is it possible to publish such papers (namely, those without policy recommendations)? I am not aiming too high and am content with journals ranked B or C (ABDC). Could anyone also suggest what to include in the discussion/conclusion sections of such papers?